# Can I use more than one internet provider at the same time?

Tags: router, internet-connection, provider

Usually a home router has only one uplink connection, enabling a single internet provider at a time. But suppose I hack my router (ie. installing linux), could I use 2 internet providers then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a linux router to load balance and share 2+ connections across a LAN.

[This article](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-load-balancing-failover-with-dual-multi-wan-adsl-cable-connections-on-linux/) explains how to edit your route tables and /etc/rc.local file to do this.

Comment: I'm interested in doing the same thing, but I already have a linux server set up as a router. I'd prefer not having to use a separate machine to install Vyatta, since it appears to require the whole machine, and not coexist with an existing linux setup. So this answer is useful to me.

Answer (score 6):

"hacking" the router may not suffice, you'll need 'load balancing'.

a spare old computer with 2 NICs and **[Vyatta Community Edition](http://www.vyatta.org/)** is certainly cheaper solution than a modern Multi-WAN router.

> When you run Vyatta on a standard x86
>   hardware system, you'll create a
>   powerful network appliance that can
>   run circles around proprietary
>   systems.

Comment: o0 interesting. +1.

Comment: beats the heck out of some $$$$ enterprise routers :)

Answer (score 2):

Only if it has two physical ports, and you've got two separate lines coming into your house. If that's the case, take a look at [this topic on the subject.](https://superuser.com/questions/91177/how-to-unite-two-lan-connections-into-one)

Answer (score 1):

Windows can load balance 2 connections. If you have a machine with 2 NICs, you can edit the registry to enable this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NetBT\Parameters]
"RandomAdapter"=dword:00000001
"SingleResponse"=dword:00000001
```

This isn't useful if you want to share the connections with a network though.