# Merging two DSL services

Tags: router, lan, routing, load-balancer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Can I use more than one internet provider at the same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/91178/can-i-use-more-than-one-internet-provider-at-the-same-time)

Hi,

I have a scenario here:

> There are two different DSL services available from different service providers.
>
> Routers from both services are assigning IP to each machine through DHCP service.
>
> both are connected to each other through Ethernet wire(Cross-Over Cabling).

Now I want to use both services at once on each machine connected to the LAN. The reason I have here is :

> All computers should be on same LAN.
>
> if both services could be used at the same time my internet speed would be double.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/108045/load-balance-with-lan-and-wi-fi | http://superuser.com/questions/140657/how-to-load-balance-2-internet-connections-on-a-windows-7-machine | http://superuser.com/questions/91178/can-i-use-more-than-one-internet-provider-at-the-same-time

Comment: Duplicate, please close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can bind two connections together with a certain type of router (but this won't necessarily "double" your throughput, it will load balance). Try the Linux solutions [LARTC](http://lartc.org/) or [IPcop](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ipcop/wiki), or get a Cisco router. There are also software packages like [Midpoint](http://www.midpoint.com/) and [SurfDoubler](http://www.surfdoubler.com/) which may help you.