# Taking advantage of two broadband links

Tags: networking, proxy, broadband

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use more than one internet provider at the same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/91178/can-i-use-more-than-one-internet-provider-at-the-same-time)

I have two broadband connections at my place, delivered via plain old Ethernet. I was wondering if I can 'load balance' my traffic with something like `Multilink PPP` but for Ethernet (Linux or Windows).

Even a multiple HTTP proxy solution would be nice too, where parallel HTTP requests randomly choose between two proxy servers, thus increasing throughput.

Comment: I have always wondered about this.  I hope you get a great answer.  =D

Comment: You can take the concept of Teaming/Link Aggregation/Bonding and apply it to this. You would need at least 3 NICs on the gateway computer. Two for your internet connections and one for your LAN/Switch. 

Your gateway computer would handle the load balancing of the network traffic. Do you need to host websites on this connection or is it just for increasing your networks internet bandwidth?

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: Why not just use load balancing or a multi-wan router? Those are the simplest and most traditional methods.

Comment: @kobaltz I just need to increase my http(multithreaded downloader) download speed.
On Linux or Windows

Comment: @A. I started investigating Zeroshell under VirtualBox. I will blog about it when I am done.